The _____ of the table from the left part of the room to the right is annoying

The _____ of the table from the left part of the room to the right is annoying.


rearrangement: I feel like I can only rearrange several things, but only one table is moved here.

movement: sounds like the table knows how to move itself.

relocation: I think this word is only used for big things like buildings, or perhaps people.


Do I understand these words correctly? Which word(s) should I use?

Moving / Repositioning the table to the right side  of the room…

None of the above.  You have to choose the least bad option.  Relocaton is least bad, IMO.  Terrible question, if it is on a test.   We can't even say if this is an expression of laziness (I don't feel like moving it) or taste (it was better on the left).

It's not on a test; it was made up by me. I was trying to see if any of them works when it comes to one small object, so I chose a table.

Edit: Moving the table from the left side of the room to the right. Test question: Why can't it be "the movement"?

Given the choice, I'd use relocation, especially if this is from a message of complaint, which are often rather formal. But the others are perfectly acceptable, and your concerns are valid, but don't make any of the expressions unnatural.
But the issue is likely not to be the relocation of the table, but its location "I'm annoyed by the table on the right side of room". If you want to focus on the action, I'd probably prefer a participle "Moving that table over there annoys me".  There are (almost) endless options here.

Are we quite sure it's not the slope of the table which is annoying?


movement/relocation/rearrangement - Which word should I use?

Short answer:
I would use movement, because it is the most generic and neutral word out of those three choices.
Additional comments:
In this exercise the words overlap. They have the same basic meaning, but there are also subtle differences. That's the most important thing to appreciate, and in that regard you have done well.
The choice of words is highly dependent on the context, and a small change in that context could easily make another word more appropriate. For example:

The rearrangement of the table from the left part of the room to the right is annoying. It leaves an odd space in the left corner and clashes with the colour of the chairs on the right hand side.

In other words, rearrangement certainly suggests more than one object. But the other objects may be explicit or implied by the context.
In the same way, relocation implies a more significant change. But if the table being moved is the presidential table at the White House, then relocation may indeed be the right word.
Finally, note that the OP reason for doubting the choice of movement (How can a table move itself?) is not relevant. In theory, that argument could be applied to all the word options. How can a table rearrange or relocate itself? The real point here is to identify the focus of the sentence. And that focus is on the fact or nature of the change, not on the agent who caused the change. We are entitled to assume that there must have been an agent, but it's not relevant to the story.

Can I use all these words (rearrangement, repositioning, movement, relocation) to talk about big changes? You said that relocation is suitable in that case; what about the other three?

Of course. "Just last night I watched a documentary about a house moving company. It contracts to relocate houses throughout New Zealand. And sometimes, when it purchases a house that would otherwise be demolished, it needs to store the house on its premises. And this may require rearranging other housing stock to make space for the new building." There, did it!
